# How can we programmatically approve merge requests in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Our group has a bot that creates merge requests for certain mechanical changes to our code base. We'd like these MRs to get merged in automatically if/when the CI pipeline succeeds, but our projects require an approval from a member of our group. This means that right now a human has to manually click on "approve" and "merge" for each bot-created MR. Apparently GitLab doesn't have a way to set different approval rules for some users, so I haven't found a way to make the bot's user immune to this requirement.

My current idea is to have a separate process that approves each of the merge requests created by the bot. Is there an easy way to do this programmatically? That is, is there an API (or better yet, a command line tool) that, when given the name of the branch for a merge request, approves the merge request associated with that branch?

I'm also open to other ways of getting these changes in with minimal human intervention. I do want them to pass the CI pipeline, though (which is currently accomplished by having them use MRs) and the MRs also help in the rare cases where the pipeline fails, so we can debug what went wrong.

In case it matters: we're using gitlab.com, and have a "silver" plan.

Comment: Did you check Gitlab Merge Request [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr) and/or Gitlab python [client](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/mrs.html) ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I looked, but was unable to find a way to approve an MR programmatically, only a way to merge one that has already been approved. I'm not too familiar with GitLab's API, though, so I'm not sure if I was just looking in the wrong place, or if there simply isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this via the GitLab API. It will be a two step process at minimum.

First, approve the merge request via the [Merge Request Approvals endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#approve-merge-request). Send a `POST` request to `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/approve`.

- `:id` is the project ID
- `:merge_request_iid` is the ID/number of the merge request itself.

Next, you can accept (merge) the merge request via the [Accept MR API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr). 
Send a `PUT` request to `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/merge` where the `:id` and `:merge_request_iid` placeholders are the same from the previous endpoint.

One note on the 'Accept MR' request is you'll want to set the attribute `merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` to `true` if you want to wait for the pipeline to succeed before merging. Otherwise, it will be merged immediately.

There are various other optional attributes that can be sent for each request. The links to the  documentation outline those attributes and their use.

Answer (score 1):

Warning, in addition to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58036578/6309) (using the [`approve`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#approve-merge-request) endpoint, as noted by [Laurence Gonsalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90848/laurence-gonsalves) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019605/how-can-we-programmatically-approve-merge-requests-in-gitlab/67248689#comment135026735_67248689)), GitLab 14 will also bring:

> ### [Removal of merge request approvers endpoint in favor of Approval Rules API](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#removal-of-merge-request-approvers-endpoint-in-favor-of-approval-rules-api)
>
> The `PUT /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/approvers` API endpoint was deprecated and scheduled for removal on September 22, 2019 due to the release of **Approval Rules**.
>
> Approval rules for merge requests allow you to communicate who should participate in code reviews by specifying the eligible approvers, and the minimum number of approvals for each.
>
> GitLab 13.11 removes support for this endpoint.
> If you currently use this endpoint, read the documentation to learn how to implement the feature using the [**Approval Rules API**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#merge-request-level-mr-approvals).

Comment: Just a bit of clarification: the linked answer isn't using the `approvers` endpoint. It's using the `approve` endpoint, which still exists to this day (GitLab 16, as I write this). You *can* programmatically approve, at least as long as your bot is using credentials that conform to the approval rules.