# Trigger Gitlab Pipeline Jobs when Merge Succeeds

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I have three K8s clusters; staging, sandbox, and production. I would like to:

1. Trigger a pipeline to build and deploy an image to staging, if a merge request to `master` is created
2. Upon a successful deploy of staging, I would like the branch to be merged into `master`
3. I would like to use the *same* image I already built in the build job before the staging deploy, to be used to deploy to sandbox and production

Something like this:

```
build:
  ... (stuff that builds and pushes "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG")
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

staging:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

sandbox:
  ...
  ?

production:
  ...
  ?
```

What I can't figure out is how to both have a successful MR at the end of the `staging` job and thereby have the pipeline merge the branch into master, and also then pass down whatever `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG` was to continue with the jobs for the sandbox and production deploys.

Comment: `What I can't figure out is how to both have a successful MR at the end of the staging job and` what you mean `how to both have successful MR` ?

Comment: Successfuly finish the pipeline in order to result in an automatic merge to master, _and_ still continue the pipeline somehow in order to run the other jobs. I'm suggesting that these are mutually exclusive, and I need some other way to run the sandbox and production jobs after the merge is complete.

Answer (score 3):

> Trigger a pipeline to build and deploy an image to staging, if a merge
> request to master is created

For first you can create rules like

```
only:
     - merge_requests
   except:
     variables:
       - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "master"
```

You can run the curl command or hit API to approve the MR
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/approve

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58036578/5525824

Document: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr

> I would like to use the same image I already built in the build job
> before the staging deploy, to be used to deploy to sandbox and
> production

You can use the `TAG_NAME: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` passing across the stages as Environment variable

You are making it really complicated ideally you can use the TAG and make it easy to manage and deploy using the CI.

Merge when MR gets merged and create TAG and build docker images with TAG name, deploy that same TAG across environment simple.

Comment: The manual MR approval seems to fly against the pipelines for MRs workflow, but I'll give it some more thought.

With regards to the your last comment: The issue is that we can't merge until the staging deploy is complete, and we can't deploy to staging until the image has been built. We're already using the git tag for naming.

Comment: got that, you can create another stage with dependency on first stage, as soon as first one complete you can merge the request